# Big O nested loop problem for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) cout << "hello"; }

Tags: logic, big-o

I am dealing with Big O nested loop problems. I have to calculate the total number of instructions that will run.I have been able to solve the problems where there was n being used in the condition of the inner loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n*n; j++)
            cout << "hello"; 
    }
```

solution= 1 +n+1 +n +n(1+n*2+1 +n*2+ n*n)

But I am unable to get my head around any solution invloving i itself in the condition.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            cout << "hello"; 
    }
```

I just dont know how to represent the i in the eqaution. Please help me here!

Comment: Draw out the first couple layers, then the last layer, and try to get the number of iterations in summation notation.

Comment: Do you need to figure out the Big O bound for this program or calculate the exact number of operations (i.e. number of times "hello" is printed)? Those are two different things.